# Python trying to sort a list alphabetically after it has been sorted numerically

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

Program: supposed to read a text and find the top ten most commonly used words and sort them by frequency, then print the list in order. (this occurs when the "--topcount" flag is called)

I am trying to slightly modify this program so that it, after finding the top 10 most common words from the text by frequency, then sorts the list alphabetically and prints that instead, so that it is in alphabetical order rather than numerical order.

current code:

```
import sys

def word_dictionary(filename):
  word_count = {} #create dict
  input = open(filename, 'r')
  for line in input:
    words = line.split()#split lines on whitespace
    for word in words:
      word = word.lower() #forces all found words into lowercase
      if not word in word_count:
        word_count[word] = 1
      else:
        word_count[word] = word_count[word] + 1
  input.close()
  return word_count


def print_words(filename):
  word_count = word_dictionary(filename)
  words = sorted(word_count.keys())
  for word in words:
    print word, word_count[word]


def get_count(word_count_tuple):
  return word_count_tuple[1]

def print_top(filename):
  word_count = word_dictionary(filename)
  items = sorted(word_count.items(), key=get_count, reverse=True)
  for item in items[:20]:
    print item[0], item[1]

def main():
  if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print 'usage: ./wordcount.py {--count | --topcount} file'
    sys.exit(1)

  option = sys.argv[1]
  filename = sys.argv[2]
  if option == '--count':
    print_words(filename)
  elif option == '--topcount':
    print_top(filename)
  else:
    print 'unknown option: ' + option
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I have attempted to do this with:

```
def get_alph(word_count_tuple):
  return word_count_tuple[0]
```

to replace the "def get_count(word_count_tuple)"  function and also modifying the "print top" function so that

```
  items = sorted(word_count.items(), key = get_alph)
```

to make a list in alphabetical order, but it did not work as intended and instead printed the first 10 words of a list of all of the words in the text sorted alphabetically.

are there any suggestions to help make this program work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the *slice* of the sorted words:

```
def print_top(filename):
    word_count = word_dictionary(filename)
    items = sorted(word_count.items(), key=get_count, reverse=True)
    for item in sorted(items[:20]):
        print item[0], item[1]
```

This first produces a sorted list by count in `items`, then sorts the first 20 of that sorted list again for the alphabetical order.

Since your `items` are `(word, count)` tuples, you don't need a sort key here; the tuples are sorted in lexicographic order too; two tuples are first compared on the first value, and only if equal, by their second value, etc.

Note that sorting the whole `word_count` item list is overkill if you only need the top K items here. Use the [`heapq.nlargest()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) here instead; it is a O(NlogK) algorithm instead of O(NlogN); for a large N (large number of words) this can make a significant difference:

```
import heapq

def print_top(filename):
    word_count = word_dictionary(filename)
    items = heapq.nlargest(word_count.items(), key=get_count)
    for item in sorted(items[:20]):
        print item[0], item[1]
```